# how to update the styles to a listview in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, listview, jquery-mobile

i am getting some data from a server and i create a ul list that i am trying to update the styles.

it seems that `listview('refresh',true)` doesn't work. I am using jqm 1.4 beta

```
function parseData(data)
{
    var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">';
    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        html = '<li>' +
            '<div data-role="collapsible">' +
                '<p>' + value.title + '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</li>';
    });
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}


var div = $('#div');
div.html(parseData(data));
div.find('ul').listview('refresh',true);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJMrj/2/)

an ideas?

Comment: looks like you are firing refresh before initialization you have to create element try this if ( div.find('ul').hasClass('ui-listview')) {
    div.find('ul').listview('refresh',true);
     } 
else {
   div.find('ul').trigger('create');
     }

Comment: `div.find('ul').listview();` only http://jsfiddle.net/SJMrj/3

Comment: @Omar you are right but how to make those collapsible work inside each li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **jQuery Mobile 1.4 Alpha 2**, `.trigger('create')` and `.trigger('pagecreate')` are deprecated and will be removed from 1.5.

The replacement of those function is `.enhanceWithin()`, when it is called on parent element, all widgets within will be enhannced.

Also, the correct syntax / markup of a collapsible is

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h4>Heading</h4> <!-- you were missing this tag -->
  <p>collapsible / expandable contents</p>
</div>
```

To enhance listview and collapsible, all you need is

```
$('#div').enhanceWithin();
```

---

### Update

Collapsibles are inheriting `margin` from parent `li`, resulting in styling collapsible's heading and content inadequately. Adding the below CSS fixes this issue.

```css
li .ui-collapsible-heading, .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

li .ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  margin-bottom: 1px !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Snm9x/)**