# Update the content of a listview on 'pageshow'

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get a listview to populate with data on "pageshow".  Using Javascript and JQM 1.3.2.
My html section  is my page

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="listPlaces">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h4>Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
  <div class="content-primary" id="content-primary"></div>
    </div>
  <div data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
```

I'm calling an external javascript:

```
 $(document).off("pageinit", "#listPlaces");
 $(document).on("pageinit", "#listPlaces", (function parseData(){
        var output = '', val;
        var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" id="listOfPlaces">';
        for (val in localStorage) {
            if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
                place = JSON.parse(localStorage[val]);
                output += '<li><div data-role="collapsible">' + '<a href="placeDetail.html?place='  + place["name"] + '">'  + place["name"] + '</a><br /><span style="font-size:10px;padding-left:20px">' + place["address"] + '</span><div></li>'
            }
        }
        output += '</ul>';
        return output;
    }));
 $(document).on("pageshow", "#listPlaces", (function() {
             alert('in pageshow');
     var div = $('#content-primary');
     div.output(parseData());
     div.find('ul').listview();
 }));
```

I see the 'in pageshow' alert, but then parseData() is not defined.  I have no idea how to fix this.  When I send output to console.log it looks fine and I can copy it into another file and have it display correctly.

Any help is appreciated.  I'm new to posting on this site so I tried to follow the rules.  Apologies in advance if I did something wrong.  I also did search the site and found this answer [how to update the styles to a listview in jquery mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217369/how-to-update-the-styles-to-a-listview-in-jquery-mobile) which helped, but I'm still stuck on this pageshow function.
Thanks

Comment: Declare output outside page events, `var output = '';`

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks ... I did try that, but it's complaining about my parseData() function:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: parseData is not defined "

Comment: Then define parseData() outside page events.

Comment: I've tried all combinations.  Right now I am turning off pageinit listeners, then declaring var output = ''; and the parseData() function.  I turn on the pageinit function, then the pageshow function.  The message now is Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'output'.  Sorry ... I'm not trying to be thick.  I think what I am attempting should work, I just don't know exactly how I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> div.**output**(parseData());

What is `.output()`?? --> maybe you are looking for `.html()`?

**This should do it:**

```
 $(document).off("pageinit").on("pageinit", "#listPlaces", parseData);

 $(document).on("pageshow", "#listPlaces", (function() {
     alert('in pageshow');
     var div = $('#content-primary');
     div.html(parseData());
     div.find('ul').listview();
 }));

function parseData(){
    var output = '', val;
    var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" id="listOfPlaces">';
    for (val in localStorage) {
        if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
            place = JSON.parse(localStorage[val]);
            output += '<li><div data-role="collapsible">' + '<a href="placeDetail.html?place='  + place["name"] + '">'  + place["name"] + '</a><br /><span style="font-size:10px;padding-left:20px">' + place["address"] + '</span><div></li>'
        }
    }
    output += '</ul>';
    return output;
}
```

Comment: OMG if I could vote you up I would!  Many many thanks!  Interestingly the list is shown sorted alphabetically in Chrome but not in Firefox ... that's my next task ... so happy to move on from this one!